# Angular Filter Service inside Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, filter, locale

first post ever so be gentle!!

Got an issue inside Angular 1.3 and using a Stateful Filter within a controller.

In short when you use the $filter('custom')(data) method as a pose to the {{ data | custom }} method - and the cutom filter updates (say a service updates), only the inline ( {{ }} ) filter updates on the view.

Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/nukioL3ORnl9KDPHmNoY?p=preview

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myStatefulFilterApp', [])
    .filter('decorate', ['decoration',
      function(decoration) {

        function decorateFilter(input) {
          return decoration.symbol + input + decoration.symbol;
        }
        decorateFilter.$stateful = true;

        return decorateFilter;
      }
    ])
    .controller('MyController', function($filter, $scope, decoration) {
      $scope.greeting = 'hello';
      // This will update
      $scope.decoration = decoration;
      // This won't
      $scope.code = $filter('decorate')($scope.greeting);
    })
    .value('decoration', {
      symbol: '*'
    });
})(window.angular);
```

I've tried a number of solutions to this problem, involving event listeners etc, but this example makes it clear that none of those will work.

It originally stemmed from using the date filter and the locale plugin that updates the locale dynamically, so that when the locale loads - the filter didn't update.

Any suggestions on how to get the code based filter to monitor (presuming $watch task of some sort) are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: To be clear - the purpose is for the $filter to update based on the actual filter (decoration) changing and not the contents to be filtered ($scope.greeting) - answer marked below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller is executed only once, not every time the scope updates. `$filter('decorate')($scope.greeting)` is evaluated when it is assigned to `$scope.code`, whereas `{{greeting | decorate}}` is evaluated every time the scope updates.
If your filter is not marked as stateful, your filter expression `{{greeting | decorate}}` will only be evaluated when `greeting` updates.
But none of this affects the behavior inside the controller.

To update `$scope.code` everytime `$scope.greeting` changes, you can indeed use `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('greeting', function(newValue) {
    $scope.code = $filter('decorate')(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I've editted slightly as I was looking for the actual inner workings of the filter to be monitored - http://plnkr.co/edit/XQ9KznazkWKQM9Hql3Pb - however it has put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
    I think you should try to use $watch.
    It will resolve the problem. 

    Here is the updated script.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4IlBIhh2JfmPcMDW0ty6?p=preview

```
    Hope this will help you.

    Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked a solution not using $watch but a function attached to ng-change in the input, hope that helps.

```
  $scope.update = function(){
    $scope.code =$filter('decorate')($scope.greeting);
    };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uPqCz2EpvjNrwCM0ztLs?p=preview